# project related to square root matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

let us consider following project
[image]

for the part 1, if we put

$(SDS^{-1})^{p/q}=SD^{p/q}S^{-1}$

first of all if   $A=SDS^{-1}$,then  $(SDS^{-1})^{p/q}=A^{p/q}$
how should i extend this any  more?for part B according to  square root definition from wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix

we can use following definition

If D is a diagonal n × n matrix, one can obtain a square root by taking a diagonal matrix R, where each element along the diagonal is a square root of the corresponding element of D. If the diagonal elements of D are real and non-negative, and the square roots are taken with non-negative sign, the matrix R will be the principal root of D.

for part $c$,we should diagonalize  given matrix  as

$A=S*D*S^{-1}$  and take square root from diagonal elements,for the $d$, matrixs are similar if following equation exist
    [image]

if $B$ has square root,then clearly  $B^{1/2}=P^{-1}*A^{1/2}*P$

that proof that matrix has square root, am i right?what about last part?please help me to check my arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it the other way round. You show that $(SD^{1/q}S^{-1})^q=SDS^{-1}$, hence $(SDS^{-1})^{1/q}=SD^{1/q}S^{-1}$. Now raise both sides to the power $p$, hence we get $(SDS^{-1})^{p/q}=SD^{p/q}S^{-1}$.

And yes, the arguments are ok.

Comment: thanks for reply,just for question $b$,how to proof it?clearly square root exist only if  diagonal elements of  $D$ are positive right?otherwise we get complex numbers

Comment: Yeah. But complex numbers are allowed, as it says.

Comment: so proof would be that if matrix  is diagonalizable,then  there exist always square root from diagonal elements?

Comment: If you allow complex numbers, then there is no unambiguous way to write square roots, even if the eigenvalues are real and positive.

Comment: thanks just one question,i got eigenvalues $9$ and $25$,clearly square roots are $3$,$-3$,$5$,$-5$  are they answers?for part $c$

Comment: @AbishankaSaha please if you  can tell me  a few words  about each part  how to solve each one?thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have too many matrices. If $A$ can be diagonalized, then let 
$$A = P D P^{-1}$$ 
Then define
$$f(A) = P f(D) P^{-1}$$.

Note, if $A$ is $n\times n$ and has $k$ non-zero eigenvalues, you can set the sign of the square root as $\pm$ to get $2^k$ square roots.

You can also get square roots that are not of the form $ P f(D) P^{-1}$. Here is an example:

Pick any $u$, $v$ and $w$ so that $u^2+v\, w = 1$. Now 
$$
B =\begin{pmatrix} u & v \\ w & -u \end{pmatrix}$$
satisfies $$
B^2 =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
But $B$ is not diagonal but $B^2$ is diagonal.

Comment: about part $e$,what does it means?

Comment: It says that to see if a matrix has a square root can be deduced by looking at its Jordan form. Two similar matrices have the same Jordan form

Comment: Jordan form makes fact that given matrix is  diagonalizable and there exist another matrix  similar to first one right?

Comment: please could  you put complete answers for each parts?just  by few words how to progress,please